# Is it possible to use ajax code on elements with the same id and check individually?

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my view I have generated `<input type="text" class="solution" name="answer" />` 3 times, accompanied with an image.
The user has to guess what the image is.
If the user enters his/her answer in the textbox and then clicks somewhere or tabs to another field, the code below runs the script and goes to check if the answer is right.
Now, the code below works just fine, except it only does this for the first textbox .

How can I let the code run on each textbox?

```
$('.solution').change(function(){               
                var form_data = {
                    name: $('.solution').val(),
                    ajax: '1'
                    };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('homework/submit'); ?>",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#message').html(msg);
                        //outputs: correct
                        },
                    error: function(msg){
                        $('#message').html(msg);
                        //outputs: wrong
                        }

                    });

                return false;
            });
```

This is my code to generate the fields:

```
$label = 1;
                $url = base_url('public/images/oefeningen');
                $dump = '';
                foreach ($result as $row)
                    {
                        $label = $row->exercise_id;
                        $arr_instructions = explode(',', $row->exercise_instruction);
                        foreach ($arr_instructions as $instruction)
                        {

                            $dump .= '<li><img src="'. $url . '/' . $instruction .'.png"/><br /><input type="text" class="solution" name="answer" /></li>';                                                             
                        }

                        $dump .= '</li>';
                    }
                    $dump .= '</ul>';
                    echo $dump;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `id` attribute must be unique.

Comment: Don't use the same ID multiple times. IDs are supposed to be unique. You can give them all the same `class` attribute.

Comment: Oh, right. Gave them the same class! Still doesn't work though! :(

Comment: if you have multiple ids it will select only the first one. id has to be unique so change it to class and it will work fine.

Comment: @JefAerts are you creating the other two dynamically? You have 3 textboxes at a time right?

Comment: @PSL Yes, I am creating the other two dynamically :)

Comment: @JefAerts Can you show your markup.. You are showing only one textbox./

Comment: @PSL I just edited my question so you could see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute must be unique. Use a `class` selector instead.

```
<input type="text" class="solution" name="answer" />

$(".solution").on("change", function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    ...
});
```